# I want to use orderBy ()and take() after where(), but it is querying just oppsite to my desired answer

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Let's assume an `Event` table, I want to get the first latest event which will be held after `current_date` and I ordered it by `event_start_date`.

But it is querying the first `orderBy` and take then running condition over it.

```
EVENT::where(Event::START_DATE, '>', 'CURDATE()')->orderBy(Event::START_DATE)->take($nThEvent)->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `whereRaw()` if you have to call sql functions, e.g.:

```php
EVENT::whereRaw(Event::START_DATE.' > CURDATE()')
    ->latest(Event::START_DATE)
    ->take($nThEvent)
    ->get()->toArray();
```

BTW you can always debug your query with `toSql()`, it returns a string with the generated SQL:

```php
EVENT::whereRaw(Event::START_DATE.' > CURDATE()')
    ->latest(Event::START_DATE)
    ->take($nThEvent)
    ->toSql();
```

Please note that `latest(Event::START_DATE)` is equal to write `orderBy(Event::START_DATE, 'desc')`.

Update: if you want to get only one record you should use `first()` not `get()` that returns instead a collection, e.g.:

```php
EVENT::whereRaw(Event::START_DATE.' > CURDATE()')
    ->latest(Event::START_DATE)
    ->first()
```

Comment: where condition is working perfectly fine if I just remove orderBy and take, but latest works fine, and toSql is really life saving, I didn't know this before, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you

```
EVENT::where(Event::START_DATE, '>', 'CURDATE()')->latest('START_DATE')->first();
```